# $L^2[0,1]$ topology or property

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is there some other topology in $L^2[0,1]$ except the norm convergence and weak convergence topology?

Comment: The discrete topology is another one.

Comment: @Crostul: The discrete one is a bad choice as the space won't be a TVS.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are many. $L^2[0,1]\subset L^p[0,1]$ if $1\le p<2$, so it can be given the topology of the $L^p$ norm (it will no be complete). You also have weighted $L^2$ norms defined as $\|f\|_{2,w}^2=\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,w(x)\,dx$ for an appropriate weight $w\colon[0,1]\to(0,\infty)$. Or consider it as a subspace of a Sobolev space of negative order. Or the topology of almost everywhere convergence.